# undefined error when array created using foreach loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, undefined

This is my code below but this throws a notice undefined variable **pgggo_u_catidexcluder**. Not sure why

Error points to

```
if(is_array($pgggo_u_catidexcluder)){
```

this the complete code

```
$pgggo_u_catidexclude = array_map('intval', $pgggo_u_catidexclude);
        foreach ($pgggo_u_catidexclude as $value) {
            $pgggo_u_catidexcluder[] = -1*$value;
        }
        if(is_array($pgggo_u_catidexcluder)){
        $pgggo_u_catidexcluder = implode (", ", $pgggo_u_catidexcluder);
        }else{
            $pgggo_u_catidexcluder = '';
        }
```

Comment: I guess `$pgggo_u_catidexcluder` in foreach loop is local variable, so when you use the same variable name out of the foreach loop will show undefined.

Comment: @tiebob thanks, Actually this is inside a class function..any way to fix it?

Comment: @tiebob Thank you. I had to define the variable before for-loop which fixes my issues

Comment: If `$pgggo_u_catidexclude` is empty your foreach-body is never executed and `$pgggo_u_catidexcluder` (with the r appended to it) probably never initialized and thus undefined.